Error: The named parameter 'child' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. Try adding the required argument
This is the code below:
`// Automatic FlutterFlow imports
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_theme.dart';
import '/flutter_flow/flutter_flow_util.dart';
import '/custom_code/widgets/index.dart'; // Imports other custom widgets
import '/flutter_flow/custom_functions.dart'; // Imports custom functions
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// Begin custom widget code
// DO NOT REMOVE OR MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE!

import 'package:flutter_map/flutter_map.dart';
import 'package:latlong2/latlong.dart' as ll;

class DynamicMap extends StatefulWidget {
  const DynamicMap({
    super.key,
    this.width,
    this.height,
    this.points,
    required this.accessToken,
    required this.startingPoint,
    required this.startingZoom,
  });

  final double? width;
  final double? height;
  final List<LatLng>? points;
  final String accessToken;
  final LatLng startingPoint;
  final double startingZoom;

  @override
  State<DynamicMap> createState() => _DynamicMapState();
}

class _DynamicMapState extends State<DynamicMap> {
  List<Marker> allMarkers = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    addMarkersToMap(widget.points);
  }

  void addMarkersToMap(List<LatLng>? points) {
    for (LatLng point in points!) {
      allMarkers.add(
        Marker(
          point: ll.LatLng(point.latitude, point.longitude),
          height: 12,
          width: 12,
          builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Icon(
            Icons.location_pin,
            color: Colors.red,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FlutterMap(
      options: MapOptions(
        center: ll.LatLng(
            widget.startingPoint.latitude, widget.startingPoint.longitude),
        zoom: widget.startingZoom,
      ),
      children: [
        TileLayer(
          urlTemplate:
              'https://api.mapbox.com/styles/v1/abdulsgilal579/clv6gzc4k007801o081vja3q9/tiles/256/{z}/{x}/{y}@2x?access_token=${widget.accessToken}',
        ),
        MarkerLayer(
          markers: allMarkers,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}`

and i am getting these 2 errors:
Erorr 1: The named parameter 'builder' isn't defined. Try correcting the name to an existing named parameter's name, or defining a named parameter with the name 'builder'.
Erorr 2: The named parameter 'child' is required, but there's no corresponding argument. Try adding the required argument.
Line 46, Character 9
I tried resolving using CHATGPT but nothing happend.

Instead of
      builder: (BuildContext ctx) => Icon(
        Icons.location_pin,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),

you need
      child: Icon(
        Icons.location_pin,
        color: Colors.red,
      ),

This is a change introduced in flutter_map in version 6.0.0 as you can see here https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_map/changelog. If you use older versions you could use the builder that you now have in your code

I'm grateful that your solution fixed the initial error. However, during testing, I encountered another issue. The error message states: 'Bad state: No element'. It seems to be related to the 'HomePageWidget'. Below is the stack trace:
dart: sdk_internal 11914:11
throw-
dart: sdk_internal 27703:19
firstl packages/dynamicmap/pages/ home_page/ home_page_model. dart.js
833:1005
build
Could you assist me with resolving this new error?"

it looks like you are using first on a list that's empty. But better to ask a new question for that, including the code of HomePageModel
